# Ativando uma session

Tags: php

Bom dia,

Estou começando a estudar sessions, mas surgiu uma duvida..
Tenho duas imagens, que ao clicar em uma, ela fica colorida e a outra preto e branco.. mas assim que eu clico em uma imagem ela da refresh na pagina, por cotna do href, logo ela nao fica selecionada, por conta do refresh.
Como eu faria para que quando eu clicasse na seguinte imagem, a session mudasse, para assim eu fazer um logica pra poder conseguir deixar ela selecionada?

No geral, é uma duvida se eu consigo alterar o conteudo da session clicando em um botão.

Grato!

Comment: Voce conseguiria enviando um form (que poderia ser so um botao com a imagem)

Comment: Pode acrescentar um parâmetro no final do link, como ?valor=1 e ?valor=2, e recuperar com $_GET['valor']. Lembrando que isso não tem nada a ver com a session diretamente. Sugeriria um outro cenário para treinar session (nem que seja um sistema simples de login, com senha "fixa", sem DB sem nada), simplesmente com opção de "Logado" ou "Não logado"

Comment: Certo, uma boa ideia usar o GET, nao tinha pensado nisso. Obrigado!!